# How to add a block to the main page region?

Tags: 7, blocks

I want to add a simple blocks in the main page region. Instead of basic page or article I just want to add 4 blocks on that page. So, it looks like, Home page(Have blocks) >> sub-Home(have blocks) >> All Basic page(content). This looks simple but there is no way in the add block options where we can display as block and have a path.

Comment: is this Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: It is Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to YOUR_SITE/admin/structure/block and find the ***Content*** region

then go to **Configure**

[image]

Then configure the **Visibility settings**, in this case this block only will be showed in the front page.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I checked, when I went to site/structure/block and there is list of all regions and there is **Main Content** and under that there is a option of **Main page content** and if I go to configure of that, under the **pages** option at bottom there is no option what you have shown in image. Moreover I guess in your first image you are describing the **view:noticias**, may be that is the block created by Views module. I am using D7. Am I missing something or i have to check somewhere else? Thx.

Comment: @codenext, the "config option" only show at the bottom after you click the on the blue configure link (see top picture, right side) It should show up regardless if its a view block or a normal block.

Comment: Hi, I have just added the screen shot of my UI in main question, but there is not a such option which you have described. Are you refering D8 or Block created by Views module. I want to do it by drupal's core block module.

Comment: @codenext this is a Drupal 7 screenshot and a block always is a block even if is created by the view module

Comment: @codenext is the same UI just select " Only the listed pages" and in the textarea put "<front>"and save. The problem is that I have others options provided by others modules.

Comment: Ya, I show again, it is same. I Agree, Thx. But please let me explain my issue. I have already created front page using page--front.tpl.php and have added 4 block on front page. now what I want if some one click the one block from the first page he should be directed to the other path, where i want to add another blocks in the main content region same as what I had added in front page. But there <front> path was there, Here I can not create new path by putting something in region of describing path. and the all available paths are creates only when we create some node.

Comment: .....<front> path is by default so it is very easy to add there by putting path <front>. Same way I want  to create another page which works like a another front page (serve same way) where I can put some another blocks. so if person clicks from front page he gets directed to this page where i do not want any basic page or article, just fours to five blocks in main content area. and from that i wnat to give individual link to articles and basic pages...so it is like Home(Have blocks) >> sub-Home(have blocks) >> Basic page(content)